# How to Interpret Profile GPU rendering graph - Android App

Tags: android, performance, profiling, performance-testing, glsurfaceview

I've a custom view which extends GLSurfaceView. I did GPU profiling of a simple app which utilizes the custom view using dumpsys gfxinfo command. I copied the data in excel and created a chart but now I'm not sure how to interpret this data for finding the problem. I understand that any frame taking more than 16ms is not good, and app may drop the frames because of that but WHAT ELSE ?!

I also got trace.html using systrace.py That is even more complicated to understand and find the real culprit.

I've attached the chart.

Thank you.
[image]

Comment: The systrace output is going to be more useful, as it shows the interaction between multiple components, not just the behavior of a single component.  Make sure you have a useful set of tags defined (e.g. gfx view sched dalvik).  The sched stuff is very useful for anything CPU-bound; see e.g. http://bigflake.com/systrace/